# Whats the difference in power consumption between a ball mouse and an optical/laser mouse?

Tags: mouse, power

What I'm interested in finding out is, if a ball mouse uses less power than an optical/laser mouse and if so, is it significant enough to warrant carrying a ball mouse with my Ubuntu laptop to save battery?

Comment: I like your idea to be practical as there are too many factors to say something generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually determining how much power a computer peripheral device is consuming is very simple. Since most peripheral devices that draws power from the PC itself only uses DC, and to calculate the power consumed by a DC device we simply need to know its voltage and current which can be obtained from the device's specification. After that apply it in the formula.

> **P = V x I**

And we will get the power consumed.

Luckily I got a ball mouse and an optical mouse both from Microsoft laying around. So I can do a little comparison of my own to show you what is the difference between the power consumption of the two mouse. The comparison should be a fair one since both the mouse are from the same manufacturer.

Ok so here are the pictures of the two mouse that I am going to use for this comparison.

The ball mouse. Almost 15 years old.
[image: The ball mouse]

The optical mouse. A couple of years old.
[image: The optical mouse]

I have marked the voltage and current in a red box. The device specs are also sometimes written on the box in which they come.

So, for the ball mouse we have: **V = 5V and I = 20mA or I = 0.02A**.

And, for the optical mouse we have: **V = 5V and I = 100mA or I = 0.1A**.

Now power consumed by the ball mouse is: **P = V x I = 5 x 0.02 = 0.1W**.

And, power consumed by the optical mouse is: **P = V x I = 5 x 0.1 = 0.5W**.

So there we have it a typical optical mouse consumes **5X** the power that of a ball mouse. Now off course this result can vary from device to device manufacturer to manufacturer. For example my Logitech G300 mouse takes in 5V, 250mA. Its needles to say it consumes 2.5X the power of the optical mouse that I have used in the example.

*Tip: You can avoid the calculation part and just compare the input current (mA) of the devices. Since most peripheral devices that takes power from the PC has a voltage rating of 5V, comparing their current will give you an idea which is more power hungry.*

Comment: Nice answer, but the figure they list is only the maximum.  It might be close to that number when it's being moved, but otherwise it's something closer to zero.

Comment: @Jason Yes I know that. The maximum power is consumed when it is moved, in idle state both will be consuming very low amount of power which is some what negligible. But we are interested in that maximum power consumption when it will be moved. Right?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be about active or maximum, but rather total consumption in a "real world" scenario.  When I'm browsing/writing I probably only have my cursor moving <2% of the time.  More importantly, some optical mice turn off the LED when idle (not sure if any mechanical mice do), while others do not.

Comment: It is true we do not use our mouse all the time. Yes the question is not about activity or maximum. What I am trying to say is that we are interested in measuring the difference in power consumption when the mouse is moved because their idle power consumption is almost negligible. It is during the movement when the actual difference in power consumption between the two comes, rest of the time its almost the same.

Comment: This was fairly enlightening. Thanks you. :-) ...although it seems like an experiment might  still be in order to see behavior of specific hardware. One could conclude that, generally speaking, a ball mouse would be likely to use less.

Comment: In case of ball mouses when there is no movement, no signals are generated. It is some what like turning off the LED in case of optical mouse. Ball mouses generate signals only during the period of movement. In case of optical mouse the once there is some movement the LED turns on and stays on a few seconds even if movement stops temporarily to detect any further movement. The LED does not turns off instantaneously, but ball mouses stops generating signals instantaneously when ever the movement stops.

Answer (score -1):

Not all optical mice use lasers (most use LEDs) and I am sure they vary in power usage.

From [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mouse#Optical_versus_mechanical_mice):

> As of 2006 mechanical mice had lower average power requirements than their optical counterparts; the power used by mice is relatively small, and only an important consideration when the power is derived from batteries, with their limited capacity.

I'm sure things have changed since 2006 though.

Comment: It would be nicer if that clause had a source. I couldn't find it from the page.

Comment: @ScottRhee I would have linked to the source instead if there was one.

Comment: Actually we can estimate the power usage of the device in hand and I have made a comparative study of the two types of mouse in question in my answer. Turns out still now the optical mouses uses comparatively high amount of power.